# How to reject double slashes with a regular expression

Tags: regex

I would like to build a regex which does:

- allow as many alphanumeric characters as wanted
- allow a `/` between the character
- must end with a `/`
- does reject any other character like a `*` etc.
- does not allow a two / behind each other (e.G. `a//b/`)

I've build the following regex: `^[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+\/$`.

The Regex Matches: `a/b/c/` or  `1/2/c/`
I would like to not match a String like `1//a/`

is this possible?

Comment: Consider: `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/$`

Comment: Use `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\/$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you may use is

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\/$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dHXsk3/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric chars
- `(?:\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - a non-capturing group that matches 0 or more repetitions of the following patterns:

  - `\/` - a `/` char
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric chars
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `$` -  end of string.

Note that `/` should not be escaped if `/` are not used as regex delimiters, or if regex delimiters are not used (in string literals, constructor notation, etc.).